# Selecting the components showing the most variance in PCA

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, classification, pca, dimensionality-reduction

I have a huge data set (32000*2500) that I need for training. This seems to be too much for my classifier, so I decided to do some reading on dimensionality reduction and specifically into PCA.

From my understanding, PCA selects the current data and replots them on another (x,y) domain/scale. These new coordinates don't mean anything but the data is rearranged to give one axis maximum variation. After these new coefficients I can drop the `cooeff` having minimum variation.

Now I am trying to implement this in MatLab and am having trouble with the output provided. MatLab always considers rows as observations and columns as variables. So my inout to the `pca` function would be my matrix of size `(32000*2500)`. This would return the PCA coefficients in an output matrix of size `2500*2500`.

The help for pca states:

> Each column of coeff contains coefficients for one principal
>   component, and the columns are in descending order of component
>   variance.

In this output, which dimension is the observations of my data? I mean if I have to give this to the classifier, will the rows of `coeff` represent my datas observations or is it now the columns of `coeff`?

And how do I remove the coefficients having the least variation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Disclaimer: it's been a long time since I switched from matlab to scipy, but the principles are the same.)

If you use the [`svd` function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/svd.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com)

```
[U,S,V] = svd(X)
```

then to reduce the dimension of `X` to `k`, you'd multiply by the first `k` columns of `V`. In matlab, I'm guessing that's

```
X * V(:, 1: k);
```

---

Refer to [Elements of Statistical Learning](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/) for the theory.

Comment: @rayryeng :-) Thank you!